# MongoDB update transforming the schema

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to transform all the documents of a collection.

For example I have

```
{
        "_id": ObjectId("5004918de59cfc4e92ba1cf6"),
        "field1": 1,
        "field2": 2,
        "field3": 3,
        "field4": 4
    }
```

and I'd like to transform like this

```
    {
    "_id": ObjectId("5004918de59cfc4e92ba1cf6"),
    "fieldSet1": {
        "field1": 1,
        "field2": 2
    },
    "fieldSet2": {
        "field3": 3,
        "field4": 4
    }
}
```

Thank's for your precious help !
Gilles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [rename](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/rename/) function of mongo.

In your example:

```
db.yourcollection.update( { _id: 1 }, 
    { $rename: { "field1": "fieldSet1.field1", 
                 "field2": "fieldSet1.field2", 
                 "field3": "fieldSet2.field3", 
                 "field4": "fieldSet2.field4", } } )
```